# jQuery.one() gets triggered twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Why does the event bound with `jQuery.one()` get triggered twice if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the input and in the same second click outside the input? As far as I know `one()` is supposed to be triggered maximum of once!

```
$('.list').one('click', 'a.save', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
...
});


 $('.list input')
.on('keypress', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13 | code == 10) {
        $this.parents('li').find('a.save').click();
    }
})
.on('blur', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('li').find('a.save').click();
});
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/BpgFz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try `.closest()` instead of `.parents()`.

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) stops traversing upwards as soon as it has a match. [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) keeps going until it's found all matching ancestors.

My guess without seeing your html (please show your markup in the question!) is that you have a nested list with multiple `.list` elements each of which has its own `.one()` handler, and your use of `.parents('li')` is finding both the inner and outer li elements, and then the outermost li element found contains more than one `.list` element and `.find('a.save')` is returning multiple elements to `.click()`.

That is, I think your code is inadvertently triggering the handler from a different list item.